# Windows 7, big malfunction when clicking on a desktop icon

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7.

Many (20 or so) dialog boxes open suddenly and uncontrollably, and ask if I want to delete the program, whenever I double click on a desktop icon. The boxes can't be closed.

The process seems to be explorer.exe according to task manager.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.  Have you tried to simply restart your computer?  This sounds like a malicous infection.

Comment: Check if your shift key isn't stuck, too.

Comment: Are you the admin or a normal user, this info will be helpful as well.

Comment: I have installed, and have run Avast regular online, and complete boot scans prior to start up.                                       Also complete scans with Malwarebytes, SuperAntiSpyware, Spyware Terminator, Spybot, Kaspersky, Norton, Emisoft, Sophos virus/malware scanners, Microsoft Security Scanner, and HitManPro and found no malware, etc. It looks like I have corrupted files.  Best way to repair???

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to try here:

- A simple restart normally works for a lot of problems
- try a system restore to a time hwn you know your machine was working correctly
- Install and try a few free anti-malware/anti-virus etc solutions to rule out viruses.  be sure to uninstall between each version as multiple AVs cause problems
- Check the *.exe file association is nto associated to a script or program - this has been known to cause behaviour similar to what you are experiencing.

Hope this helps